# How to match associative array keys against array values without a loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, matching

The question pretty much says it all.

Im trying to match the keys of one array, to the values of another in php, without the use of a loop. Thanks :)

I could create an array by naming all the keys to the value i want to match against and set the value to null and check the key intersection, but this just seems inefficient. There probably is a simpler way to it, if anyone knows :)

For example

```
$array1 = array('photo' => 'foo.jpeg', 'audio' => 'bar.mp3');
$array2 = array('photo', 'audio', 'video');
```

Im trying to get any value of $array2 to match with any of the keys of $array1

Comment: i've updated the question, please do check

Comment: What do you want when there is a match the value from `$array1`, the index of `$array2`?

Comment: I want to grab the key that matched with the value.

Comment: Where is the multidimensional array ? Without a loop you will need to test for the existence of each key separately eg. `array_key_exists('photo', $array1);` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods.

```
<?php
$a = array_keys( array('photo' => 'foo.jpeg', 'audio' => 'bar.mp3') );
$b = array('photo', 'audio', 'video');

//This will return empty array
print_r(array_values( array_diff($a, $b) ));

//This will return array with "video".
print_r(array_values( array_diff($b, $a) ));

//This will check Double sided array so the response 
// will be element missing from both arrays.
print_r(array_values(array_merge(array_diff($b, $a), array_diff($a, $b))));
```